# Android calendar (caldroid) create 2 calendar views

Tags: android, calendar, caldroid

Hi I'm using Caldroid calendar, and I use initialization code from official site only I use `getFragmentManager()` instead `getSupportFragmentManager()` because I use code in class which extend from Fragment not Activity. MysTab is fragment of TabbedActivity. In result I have 2 calendars and I do not know why. Any ideas?

**Screenshot**

[image]

```
public class MysTab extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logs_tab, container, false);

        CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.caldroidCal, caldroidFragment);
        t.commit();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/caldroidCal"
        android:name="com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide whether you want to add a calendar dynamic or use what a layout gives to you.

1. If you want to add a calendar dynamic then your code should look like this:

   ```
   public class MysTab extends Fragment {

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              return inflater.inflate(R.layout.logs_tab, container, false);
       }

       @Override
       public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();

              Bundle args = new Bundle();
              Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
              args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
              args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
              caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

              FragmentTransaction t = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
              t.replace(R.id.caldroidCal, caldroidFragment);
              t.commit();
       }

   }
   ```

   And in the same time your layout should be look like this:

   ```
      <LinearLayout
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

              <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/caldroidCal" />

      </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. If you want to add a calendar fragment static then you just need to create a fragment and inflate your layout. No need to create a fragment manually:

   ```
   public class MysTab extends Fragment {

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              return inflater.inflate(R.layout.logs_tab, container, false);
       }

   }
   ```

   And layout looks like that:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

       <fragment
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:name="com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment"
           android:id="@+id/caldroidCal" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```